# Нужно изменить внешний вид и когда не выбран и нажат Print тогда выводилось ничего не выбрано

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
checkbutton_frame = tk.Frame(root)
checkbutton_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)

def display():
    # clear listbox
    selected_item.delete(0, 'end')
    # add selected items in listbox
    for text, var in zip(cb_list, cb_var):
        if var.get():
            # the checkbutton is selected
            selected_item.insert('end', text)

cb_list = ['black','green','blue','red','white'] 
cb_var = []  # to store the variables associated to the checkbuttons
cl = 1
for r, op in enumerate(cb_list):
    var = tk.BooleanVar(root, False)
    cb = tk.Checkbutton(checkbutton_frame, variable=var, text=op, relief='ridge')
    cb.grid(row=r, column=cl, sticky="w")
    cb_var.append(var)

selected_item = tk.Listbox(root, width=30, height=20)
selected_item.grid(row=1, column=6, padx=20, pady=20, columnspan=2, sticky='e')

display_button = tk.Button(root, text='Print', command=display)
display_button.grid(row=1, column=8, padx=20, pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: 1-изображение]

Нужно сделать похожим на это и когда не выбран и нажат Print тогда выводилось "ничего не выбрано"

[image: 2-изображение]

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Можно в цикле вывода запоминать, было ли что-то вставлено в список. Если ничего не было вставлено, то выводить соответствующее сообщение:

```
def display():
    something_inserted = False  # Пока ничего не было вставлено
    # clear listbox
    selected_item.delete(0, 'end')
    # add selected items in listbox
    for text, var in zip(cb_list, cb_var):
        if var.get():
            # the checkbutton is selected
            selected_item.insert('end', text)
            something_inserted = True  # Запоминаем, что что-то было вставлено
    
    if not something_inserted:  # Если ничего не вставлено...
        selected_item.insert('end', "Ничего не выбрано")
```